Mixing audio streams to send as a single wave stream in C#
I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction here.
I'm trying to mix separate wave streams for clients connected to a voice chat server in to a single wave stream for transmitting in the voice channel.
I've tried so many things but haven't had any luck in terms of propper audio and no errors.
I've tried designing a custom memory stream mixer class and have tried using NAudio which I feel would be the best solution but have had no real luck.
I've seen a couple of videos online about how to do this but I'm completely blind from birth and there were no actual code samples with the videos.
I have some code here which theoretically should work but doesn't appear to do so.
Any help with this would be very much appreciated.
Here's my code:
        private async Task HandleClientAudioStreamAsync(TcpClient client, SslStream sslStream, string username)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[65536 * 2];

            try
            {
                int clientChannelId;
                int currentClientChannelId;

                if (!ClientChannelMap.TryGetValue(client, out clientChannelId))
                {
                    return; // Client not yet joined to channel
                }

                var channelMixer = GetOrCreateMixer(clientChannelId);

                while (true)
                {
                    ClientChannelMap.TryGetValue(client, out currentClientChannelId);
                    if (currentClientChannelId != clientChannelId)
                    {
                        clientChannelId = currentClientChannelId;
                        channelMixer = GetOrCreateMixer(clientChannelId);
                    }

                    int bytesRead = await sslStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        // Client disconnected
                        break;
                    }

                    // Convert byte array to ISampleProvider
                    var sampleProvider = ByteArrayToSampleProvider(buffer, bytesRead);

                    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        channelMixer.AddMixerInput(sampleProvider);

                        // Send mixed audio data to clients in the same channel
                        foreach (var (otherClient, otherSslStream, otherUsername) in ChannelConnectionLists[clientChannelId].ToArray())
                        {
                            if (_voiceFeedback == 0 && otherClient != client)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    var mixedStream = new MemoryStream();
                                    var waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(mixedStream, WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(32000, 2));

                                    var bufferData = new float[buffer.Length];
                                    var samples = channelMixer.Read(bufferData, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    waveFileWriter.WriteSamples(bufferData, 0, samples);

                                    var mixedBytes = mixedStream.ToArray();
                                    await otherSslStream.WriteAsync(mixedBytes, 0, mixedBytes.Length);
                                    await otherSslStream.FlushAsync();
                                }
                                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                                {
                                    _eventLog.WriteEntry("Attempted to write to a disposed SslStream.", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    _eventLog.WriteEntry($"Error sending audio data: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _semaphore.Release();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _eventLog.WriteEntry($"Error handling client audio stream: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Remove the client from all channels and clean up
                RemoveClientFromCurrentChannel(client, sslStream, username);

                lock (Lock)
                {
                    ConnectedClients.RemoveAll(x => x.client == client);
                }

                sslStream.Close();
                sslStream.Dispose();
                client.Close();
                _eventLog.WriteEntry("Client disconnected.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
        }

        private MixingSampleProvider GetOrCreateMixer(int channelId)
        {
            if (!ChannelMixers.TryGetValue(channelId, out var mixer))
            {
                mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(32000, 2)); // Set appropriate format
                ChannelMixers[channelId] = mixer;
            }
            return mixer;
        }

        private ISampleProvider ByteArrayToSampleProvider(byte[] buffer, int bytesRead)
        {
            var waveStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead), WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(32000, 2));
            return waveStream.ToSampleProvider();
        }

This should work and compiles ok but it just doesn't do as I expect.
Thanks again for your time.
Update:
I've managed to somewhat solve the issue using MixingWaveProvider but am getting stuttering audio when more than two clients connect.
At least I appear to be on the right track now, I will try wrapping the MixingWaveProvider32 in a BufferedWaveProvider to see if that mitigates the issue.
